# How to write a text file with fixed line lengths?

Tags: c#

I need to write some data into a text file, where all lines should be of equal length(size) irrespective of obtained data (the empty spaces shall be added accordingly, all data is of same type), so that I can read any specific line. Below is the current code.

```
StreamWriter stw = File.CreateText("output.txt");
foreach (var result in resultData)
{
    stw.WriteLine($"{result.Value}:{result.Date}");
}
```

[Click here to see expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr4T3.png)

Tried giving blank space, but need a generic solution

Comment: Have a read here: https://www.includehelp.com/dot-net/padding-an-integer-number-with-leading-and-trailing-spaces-zeros-in-csharp.aspx

Comment: just use some formatting when constructing string `$"{result.Value,10}:{result.Date,30}"`

Comment: Thanks Pawel & Mario, but I need a generic solution, if the data type is int, I can also get max int data which should also fit.

Comment: @vin I don't see a reason why this can't be used as a generic solution. Maybe there is a valid case but you are not giving us the full picture that only you know.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on the requirements? Are there always two columns? Do you know the column widths up-front or do you need to calculate it on the fly? What do you mean by "generic solution"?

Comment: Hi Pawel,  I mean in one case all data can be int,  one data can have max int value and other data can be max int value, so appropriate max spaces should be added.

Comment: Hi Klaus, there are only 2 columns, column width need to be calculated on the fly.

Comment: .Please [edit] your question to include this new information

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a `Result` class something like

```
class Result
{
    public int Value { get; set; } // May be double etc.
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

You can dynamically compute the max length of the values and print them like this:

```
var resultData = new List<Result>
{
    new Result { Value = 123, Date = "21.09.2023" },
    new Result { Value = 123456, Date = "21.09.2023" },
    new Result { Value = 12, Date = "21.09.2023" }
};

// Compute the max length of the Value property values
int maxLength = resultData.Max(res => res.Value.ToString().Length);
int dateOffset = maxLength + 1;

foreach (var result in resultData)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Value.ToString().PadRight(dateOffset) + result.Date);
}
```

The results are

```
123    21.09.2023
123456 21.09.2023
12     21.09.2023
```

Comment: I tried it , but one problem is the list gets updated periodically with different values, and it is not hold constant items. Anyway thanks for the support

Comment: When the list updated then check if there is any value whose length is greater than the current max length and reformat accordingly.

Comment: But we should not re-write the lines, as the list is huge

Comment: How is the list updated? Is the item count fixed and are the values updated only? Are new items added? If so, are they added as batch?

Comment: yes, items count is same, but different values are updated at regular interval

Comment: Is it possible to get max length of the datatype, ex if data type is int then find the length of max int value, if long then length of float max value ?

Comment: Yes, `int.MaxValue.ToString().Length` will return it for `int` type.

Comment: Maybe you can get this max length for your current data type and then pre-set it as `maxLength` in my code example. This may get the job done.

Comment: You should be more careful with the floating types, though.

Comment: I think should +1 to maxvalue, because min value contains - as extra length